# Do "America we need" articles describe a position of Democracy party?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, democratic-party

Some times ago, NYTimes started a series of articles called ["America we need"](https://www.nytimes.com/series/the-america-we-need), with such well-known authors as [Samuel Scheffler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Scheffler), for example, or Tim Wu[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Wu). This is an enough big series of articles, describing exactly what it is called by - "America we need".

Some bright points from that articles:

- reforming election system, with increasing role of voting by post
- free credits for afro-americans and afro-americans business
- increasing heritage taxes

Such huge amount of well-known authors and status of the NYTimes as, mostly Democratic newspaper, causing a question: is this series of articles an accurate representation of the positions of the Democratic party?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "can be treated"? Treated in what context?

Comment: Can such a big publication in NYTimes be used to make a view of Democracy party program? NYTimes is Dem.party-oriented newspaper, so I think that it is logical, but maybe there already are some official commentaries, ruining that assumption. "Treated" in the direct mean of the word. For example, if D.Trump asid something, it can be treated as President of the US words and position.

Comment: So you asking if the NY Times speaks for the Democratic party? Or if this series of articles accurately represents the position of the Democratic party?

Comment: @Philipp, the second one. NYTimes is still a newspaper, not a press-center.

Comment: I think that question would be too broad. There are 58 articles in that series. We would have to look at ever single one and compare it with the official positions of the Democratic party.

Comment: Would the question be more strict, if it would be asked about exactly mentioned points?

Comment: I think that if you would pick **one** of these points, then the question would be answerable. If you are interested in the positions of the Democratic party on multiple different issues, then you could open one question for each.

Comment: @Phillip, logical. I'll try to pick some particular points

Comment: I will then close the question until you did that edit.

Comment: But seems, that JamesK answer is enough good to answer question as a whole, isn't it?

Comment: You think so? It seems to answer the question "Does the NY Times speak for the Democratic Party" which you said is not what you want to know. You said you wanted to know how well it fits the party platform, which this answer does not answer. But if you are happy with it, then please edit the question accordingly and I reopen it.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not a Democratic party program, in any useful way.

There are many organisations that are generally "progressive" or "liberal" in US politics. The Democratic party is one, the New York Times is another.  A democratic party program would be planned by a leader or committee in the Democratic party.

A series of articles published by a newspaper, even one that is generally sympathetic to the Democrats, even one that is intended to influence thought and policy within the Democratic party is still not a program of the party.

A series of articles published on the website "democrats.org" may be considered a "program of the party", since the party plans the series and has some kind of editorial control.

The articles cannot be said to represent the position of the Democratic party. For that, see the 2020 party platform, which is published at the convention. No doubt the authors of the pieces hope it will inform and influence the platform, but no more can be said.